# GWT, RPC, and SQL, does your resultset remain server-side or can you utilise it client side?

Tags: javascript, java, sql, gwt

I have briefly changed from Android to GWT to make my app work online now.

I realise that there are many differences from Android apps to GWT projects, but one of them, I cannot wrap my head around, so maybe some one of you can clear it up for me.

I have access to my database through RPC and I can send this data to my GUI through a DefaultCallback with an onFailure and OnSuccess. Like this:

```
@Override
public void sayHello(String name) {
    this.serviceAsync.sayHello(name,  new DefaultCallback());
}

    private class DefaultCallback implements AsyncCallback {

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        System.out.println("An error has occured");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Object result) {
        System.out.println("Response received");
        if (result instanceof String) {
            mainGUI.updateLabel(String.valueOf(result));
        }
    }
}
```

**SQL** comes into the play as I access my database here, right?, so let us say I want to fill a table of accounts. I would access the table, make a loop, and then populate the table.

I utilise the SQL like so:

```
        Connection c = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("server");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return c;
```

And a resultset like so:

```
    ResultSet myGet(Connection db, String sql){
    try {
        return db.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

However, going from a databaseHelper in Android where I could easily run a cursor and then utilise my data from that cursor in loops and so on, I find this "defaultCallback" method above to be very very rigid.

As such, my question is:
**Is there a tip/trick to add some flexibility to this? So as to make it more similar to the way you would utilise a resultSet in Java or a Cursor in Android?**

Comment: how is serviceAsync related to GWT?

Comment: How is this related to the <sql> _language_?

Comment: Ok, let me add some more context then to make it relevant to that.

Comment: Alexei, the serviceAsync is just called from the MainGUI. serviceImpl.sayHello();

Answer (score 0):

First I would not go with GWT RPC nowadays. I would go with a REST-ful approach. For example domino-rest (https://github.com/DominoKit/domino-rest) is a great implementation to use on the client side. On the server side, you can use Spring Boot or jersey or something like that to provide a restful service. Besides that you need a separate data model to transport your result to the client (which needs to be serialized and deserialized for transport). On the server side you'll have a resource, which does the database request and map the result into the data object.

Here you'll find an example:

https://github.com/NaluKit/nalu-examples/tree/master/devkexample

Inside the PersonService-class (https://github.com/NaluKit/nalu-examples/blob/master/devkexample/devkexample-server/src/main/java/de/gishmo/example/devk/server/service/PersonService.java) you'll do your db request and map your data.

Comment: But in these examples, you would have to know the exact form that your data "is". What if my data: let us say columns and rows change day by day. So for example in my android app, I would run a loop on both getColumnCount and getCount so as to populate a table.

Comment: Why would you not use rpc these days? And just for curiousity, would you be able to skip the update through the defaultCallback onSuccess and do it directly in the sayHello method by returning result from the defaultCallback.

Comment: 1. you can use String[][].

Comment: 2. nope ... in opposite to your Android app, the data needs to be serialized between the client and the server. So, result will not be available on the client side - except it can be transpiled ... whiuch I do not believe

Comment: But surely there must be a way to do the following then: 1. Call method to get data from server (either RCP or Rest-ful etc). 2. Await the AsyncTask. 3. Serialize the data (could be Json or something similar, right?). 4. Send the data to global variable. 5. Wait is over, so the task 2 is resolved and method continues.

Comment: sure, that's what the LIstController does: https://github.com/NaluKit/nalu-examples/blob/master/devkexample/devkexample-client/src/main/java/de/gishmo/example/devk/client/ui/application/content/list/ListController.java. Look inside the start-method.

Comment: I am looking at it. Trying to understand it, but it seems a little too much for what I am doing now. I am just trying to do a simple test where my UI-activity is able to use some data from a db-table to set some text for example. I know I can do this with the code I have above, I just need to add the AsyncCallback method into the UI-activity, but I would much rather "pack" that code into a different class, but then it gets murky for me, and the UI finishes before the AsyncCallback is finished, and I cannot even figure out to"stop" the UI from from finishing first.